# Adicionar Autenticação em projeto Asp.net Core

Tags: autenticação, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

Criei um projeto Asp.Net Core MVC sem autenticação.

Com o projeto já em andamento, preciso adicionar a parte de autenticação e queria poder gerar automaticamente todos os arquivos que seriam gerados se eu tivesse colocado "Individual User Authentication" na criação do projeto.

Como faço para mudar a autenticação de "No Authentication" para "Individual User Authentication" e gerar esses arquivos depois do projeto ser criado?

Comment: Exite o IdentityServer, fiz uma talk sobre ele e subi alguns exemplos https://github.com/joaomello/talks/tree/master/meetup

Answer (score -1):

Você vai ter que utilizar o Identity framework para isso, e criar as telas e classes dele manualmente.

Aqui tem um [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity) para a documentação oficial (em ingles) de como fazer isso.